# Facebook login php in subfolder

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, facebook-login

I've got a problem with my php Facebook login.

If I use this script

```
   <form action="http://www.bparty.org/LOGIN/1353/fbconfig.php">
              <p> <input type="submit" name="fb" value="Login con Facebook" class="button"> </p>
         </form>
```

it works fine, but when I try to use this script:

```
 <form action="facebook/fbconfig.php">
          <p> <input type="submit" name="fb" value="Login con Facebook" class="button"> </p>
     </form>
```

that points to : www.bparty.altervista.org/IOS/IOS/facebook/fbconfig.php

it doesn't work, Facebook gives me an error that says:

The URL you entered is not allowed by the application configuration : One or more of the URLs entered are not permitted by the settings of the application . The URL must match that of the website or the application's main page or the domain must be a subdomain of a domain application .

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the second URL (www.bparty.altervista.org/IOS/IOS/facebook/fbconfig.php) to your app settings in Facebook? This URL needs to be added as a valid OAuth redirect URI, otherwise Facebook will reject login attempts with the error you received.

You can add this URL by going to your App Dashboard on Facebook and clicking Settings > Advanced, then add the URL in the OAuth Settings section.